# Turn off echo out Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a command which gets share sizes - however it spams the console with errors due to permissions based on who runs the script naturally.

```
 $shareSize = [math]::round((Get-ChildItem $($share.path) -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum ).Sum/1GB)
```

I would like to suppress the errors, like turning ECHO OFF if possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suppress error messages by redirecting the error stream to `$null`, e.g.:

```
[math]::round((Get-ChildItem $($share.path) -Recurse -Force 2>$null
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the ErrorAction parameter to your call to Get-ChildItem (I assume this is where the errors are coming from), like so:

```
 $shareSize = [math]::round((Get-ChildItem $($share.path) -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum ).Sum/1GB)
```

Please look into ErrorAction and the $ErrorActionPreference built-in variable (get-help about_Preference_Variables) for more detail. And be careful with these options -- it's usually not a good idea to hide errors.